# How to record each number for calculation in each label?

Tags: c#

[image]
Currently I use the if-else statement to indicate that if label.text is 25, it will stop adding.
It does work, But it work one label only.Other label can't continue add the number if I type the related subject.

```
if (label21.Text != "25" && label20.Text != "25" && label19.Text != "25" && label18.Text != "25" && label17.Text != "25")
            {
                if (listBox1.Items.Count != 5)
                {
                    string sbj_inc = textBox7.Text;

                    switch (sbj_inc)
                    {
                        case "Physics":
                            phy = phy + 1;
                            label21.Text = phy.ToString();
                            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox7.Text + "\t" + textBox8.Text);
                            break;

                        case "Chemistry":
                            che = che + 1;
                            label20.Text = che.ToString();
                            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox7.Text + "\t" + textBox8.Text);
                            break;

                        case "English":
                            eng = eng + 1;
                            label9.Text = eng.ToString();
                            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox7.Text + "\t" + textBox8.Text);
                            break;

                        case "Mandarin":
                            bc = bc + 1;
                            label18.Text = bc.ToString();
                            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox7.Text + "\t" + textBox8.Text);
                            break;

                        case "Melayu":
                            bm = bm + 1;
                            label17.Text = bm.ToString();
                            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox7.Text + "\t" + textBox8.Text);
                            break;

                        default:
                            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Subject");
                            break;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Maximum 4 Subjects can be chosen !");
                }

            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Class Full");
            }
```

Comment: Sounds like maybe you need to check only the label value for the specific subject being entered. So: wait until you know the specific subject before checking the label value. And then only check that one label, not all of them! It's a logic/process issue really, rather than a programming one. If you struggle with this, write down your desired process as a series of steps on paper, in normal language, such than a human could carry out the procedure correctly. After you are happy with that, then you can create the C# code to implement it. This will help you organise your thoughts before coding.

Comment: You'll need to move your if statements down into each `case` block to test if that subjects label is `25` or not and continue (or not) with just that `case` block's code for that subject.

Comment: @ADyson really thanks, cuz it's first year I learn the programming, thank for advice

Answer (score 2):

Here's the quick rewrite from my comment and @ADyson:

```
                if (listBox1.Items.Count != 5)
                {
                    string sbj_inc = textBox7.Text;

                    switch (sbj_inc)
                    {
                        case "Physics":
                            if (label21.Text != "25"){
                                phy = phy + 1;
                                label21.Text = phy.ToString();
                                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox7.Text + "\t" + textBox8.Text);
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Chemistry":
                            if (label20.Text != "25"){
                                che = che + 1;
                                label20.Text = che.ToString();
                                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox7.Text + "\t" + textBox8.Text);
                            }
                            break;

                        case "English":
                            if (label19.Text != "25"){
                                eng = eng + 1;
                                label9.Text = eng.ToString();
                                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox7.Text + "\t" + textBox8.Text);
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Mandarin":
                            if (label18.Text != "25"){
                                bc = bc + 1;
                                label18.Text = bc.ToString();
                                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox7.Text + "\t" + textBox8.Text);
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Melayu":
                            if (label17.Text != "25"){
                                bm = bm + 1;
                                label17.Text = bm.ToString();
                                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox7.Text + "\t" + textBox8.Text);
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Subject");
                            break;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Maximum 4 Subjects can be chosen !");
                }
```